# Pipeline for Amazon EC2 Mac instance patching

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, terraform, pipeline, packer

In our project, we are using EC2 Mac instance to run an automation script. We will need to patch the instance once a month or whenever there is an update available. We will need to set up a pipeline that will perform this patching job, that is, build a macOS AMI (patched AMI) and deploy new EC2 instances by replacing the old ones.

Packer can be used to build macOS AMI. We can use Packer along with AWS CodeBuild to build macOS AMI. However, for deployment, we are searching for the right option. We can't use the AWS Autoscale group since ASG doesn't support EC2 Mac instances as of now. Can someone help us here? Can we use any other approach to replace the old Mac instances with the new instances provisioned using the new AMI?